# Python механизм обхода списков в цикле for

Tags: list, python-3.6, for, compression

Помогите разобраться. Нужно вывести матрицу в таком виде

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

на ввод подаются только  Количество строк и столбцов. Задача вроде не сложная, но я не до конца понимаю механику обхода списков в цикле. 
Хотелось бы посмотреть на решение с помощью цикла и генератора списков

Comment: Где в вопросе хоть один список, о которых спрашивается? У вас заголовок об одном, вопрос о другом, а задача вообще о третьем и слабо связана с первыми двумя.

Comment: Используя генератор списка выведите матрицу вида(см.условие) n*m. Это все условие задачи.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы было понятно о чем он. Сейчас непонятно, в чем конкретно он заключается.

Comment: `n`, `m` - размерности массива (матрицы). Внешний цикл - по `n`, вложенный - по `m`. Внутри счетчик, значение которого заносится в матрицу. Работайте :)